# Unity HttpWebRequest response shows as HTML instead of XML

Tags: c#, xml, api, unity-game-engine, post

I'm trying to make a POST request from Unity using HttpWebRequest WebRequest, I get only HTML code while in Postman I get the right results.

I have tried using HttpWebRequest with StreamWriter, I tried doing it in normal way and async.

The function I use

```cs
    public void GetResults()
    {
        byte[] bytes;
        bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF - 8\"?><blabla>asdasd</blabla> ");
        string str = "[MY_API]";
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(str);
        req.Method = "POST";
        req.ContentType = "text/xml";
        string strRequest = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
        req.ContentLength = strRequest.Length;
        StreamWriter streamOut = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream(), System.Text.Encoding.ASCII);
        streamOut.Write(strRequest);
        streamOut.Close();
        StreamReader streamIn = new StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
        string strResponse = streamIn.ReadToEnd();
        print(strResponse);
        streamIn.Close();

    }
```

The expected print is XML code with some data, but actual print is

```html
<html>
<body>
<h1>
200
</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: wouldn't hurt to show us the post man request by clicking code (under send/save button) and choosing curl.

Comment: ```xml
POST  HTTP/1.1
Host: [MY API]
Content-Type: text/xml
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.18.0
Accept: */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: [TOKEN]
Host: [MY API]
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Length: 455352
Connection: keep-alive
cache-control: no-cache

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<asd> 
blablabla
</asd>
```

Comment: the accept is set to */* in postman, so that's probably what you need

Comment: Didn't change anything. After playing a little bit with the code I have another error now:  ArgumentException: Specified value has invalid Control characters.
Parameter name: value
and as I can see it is because of using Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes([string length 50k+]); on a huge string. This might be the last blocker I think.

Comment: With more debugging I found that this is where I get the error:
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

Comment: well if getting it all at once it to big, there is a getrequeststreamasync you could try.

Comment: @terrencep the problem is in request.getResponse and not in getStream

Comment: before trying that have you tried a different encoding, do you know which control character you are getting like |

Comment: I tried default, UTF8, ASCII. None worked, I want UTF8.

Comment: Use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and compare the first request in the postman results to the request you are getting in c#.  The default haeaders iin c# are different from postman.  The solution is to modify c# headers so they look eactly like the postman headers.  It looks like postman is using gzip and the issue may just be in c# you need to unzip the response before processing.

Answer (score 0):

I have used Unity3dAzure opensource awesome package, RESTClient
It solved all my problems. Very easy use.

https://github.com/Unity3dAzure/RESTClient

Note: It looks like for XML what I'm doing is not enough, this package handles XMl and JSON in a good way.